# Wordpress 4.4: Change max_srcset_image_width in media.php from functions.php

Tags: wordpress, hook, srcset

Wordpress defines the maximum resolution included in the new srcset attribute in the media.php with the following line:

```
$max_srcset_image_width = apply_filters( 'max_srcset_image_width', 1600, $size_array );
```

Is there any way to change that value (via hook etc) from my themes functions.php? Right now I changed it in the media.php itself (which is not recommended – I know...).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had success adding this to my functions.php file

```
function new_srcset_max($max_width) {
    return 2000;
}

add_filter('max_srcset_image_width', 'new_srcset_max');
```

Comment: Works like a charm! Thank you sir